Easier way to select a string in EF Core?
I would like to get the value of @@SERVERNAME. The following code works:
[Keyless]
public class EntityString
{
    public String Value { get; set; } = String.Empty;
};

// inside MyDbContext.OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityString>();

// inside MyDbContext
public IQueryable<EntityString> QueryServerName()
     => Set<EntityString>().FromSqlRaw("SELECT @@SERVERNAME as Value");

// At usage site
ServerName = (await WHContext.QueryServerName().FirstAsync()).Value

However it seems overly complex for the simple task. Is there an easier way to execute a SELECT query that is expected to return a single string value?
Using String instead of EntityString gave a runtime error that an entity class was required .

Probably context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select ...").Single() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types

@JeremyLakeman I got something working based on your comment but with some changes, thanks

I always prefer Dapper for things like that. Even though creating a context is a light-weight operation, Dapper only requires a connection and a simple query call. That's about as simple and fast as it gets.

Another option might be to add ServerName to your model, although not so useful if you only want a single column single row. public static string ServerName() => throw new NotImplementedException(); and modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(methodOfServerName, builder => builder.IsBuiltIn().HasTranslation(args => new SqlFragmentExpression("@@SERVERNAME")))

I don't see how the "duplicate" is a duplicate... it doesn't have any example of selecting a string, and most of the answers are more complicated than my original code

The top answer there shows that in EF Core 7+ you can simplify to context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS Value").Single()

You can do something like this
// Inside MyDbContext.OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<string>().HasNoKey().ToView("ServerName");

// Inside MyDbContext
public async Task<string> GetServerNameAsync()
{
    return await Set<string>().FromSqlRaw("SELECT @@SERVERNAME as 
       Value").FirstOrDefaultAsync() ?? string.Empty;
}

// At usage site
ServerName = await WHContext.GetServerNameAsync();


Is there any downside to having two levels of await  (compared to my answer that only awaits once) ?

@MM see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html. You would need to move the ?? string.Empty bit to the outside, as it won't work directly on the Task. Arguably it's not necessary anyway: by definition it will always return exactly one non-null value.

The following change worked:
// In MyDbContext class
public IQueryable<String> QueryServerName()
     => Database.SqlQueryRaw<String>("SELECT @@SERVERNAME as Value");

// usage 
ServerName = await MyContext.QueryServerName().SingleAsync();

Using SqlQuery gave an error that string could not be converted to FormattableString.
Omitting the as Value from the query string gave a runtime error "No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'. Invalid column name 'Value'."

@Charlieface so that I can have that class member function QueryServerName, and then await on it at the call site

@Charlieface sorry, the EntityString was a typo. Agree that AsQueryable is redundant, have edited my answer
